# Change to type password onblur

Tags: html, forms

I try to do a form with the information in the same input. It works fine in all the inputs but in the password it would be better if it could change to points when the user introduces the password. I want it to be type text and change to type password ONLY when the user introduces the password. The problem is in the last line of code:

I have it life here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nt9gx/

```
<form> 

<input type="text" name="name" value="name" 
    onfocus="if (this.value=='name') this.value = '';" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'name';"  
/>

<input type="text" name="password" value="password"   
    onfocus="if (this.value=='password') this.value = '' type = password;" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'password';"
           "if (this.value!=''|| 'password') type = password ;" 
/>

</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="password" name="password" value="password"` etc...

Comment: Please do not update the question with all the suggestions made in the answers, as they get needless and you will end up with a question that is actually the answer. :) By the way, I've updated my answer with the JavAscript solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the HTML5 placeholder**

To get the job done, you should simply use the HTML5 `placeholder`-attribute, like this:

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

As this will:

- show the placeholder, while no text is inserted or if all text is removed again
- it shows the text even on a password field
- no need using JavaScript

**By the way:**

- you used two times `onblur` on the last input, this should occur only once
- <del>the last line is syntactically wrong, as you need to escape the word **password** in `'` (single quotes) instead of `"` (double quotes)</del> (question was updated)
- the last line uses an undefined variable called `password` in `|| password)`
- use `type="password"` for input fields that handle, well, passwords, as the input will be "invisible"

**Note:**

If you still want to use JavaScript, you have to change the input from `type="text"` to `type="password"` within the focus and blur events by simply updating the `type`-attribute.

This is how you can do it:

```
<input type="text" name="password" value="password"   
    onfocus="if (this.value == 'password') { this.value = '', this.setAttribute('type','password'); }" 
    onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'password', this.setAttribute('type','text'); }"
>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ps8N/​

Comment: Both solutions are very good. Thank you so much. The html 5 option is the easiest but I should provide too the other solution for IE8 and previous in any case. Is that right?

Comment: You're very welcome. :) If you need it for IE8 (or even older) too, you should go with the JavaScript approach.

Comment: I would like to forget about IE8 but unfortunately there are many people using it. So the javascript seems the best option to everyone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="name" 
    onfocus="if (this.value=='name') this.value = '';" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'name';"  
/>

<input type="password" name="password" value="password"   
    onfocus="if (this.value=='password') this.value = '';" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'password';"
    onblur="if (this.value!=''|| password) value = 'password';" 
/>
```

you entered a double quote!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the password input like this :

```
<input type="text" name="password" value="password" type="password" 
    onfocus="if (this.value=='password') this.value = '';" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'password';"
/>
```

Yoc can add more conditions in `if (this.value=='')` but do it just in this `onblur` and do not write another `onblur`

You have `this.value = "password"` in the last line which is wrong and you must use `'password'` instead of `"password"`

in the last if condition you have the parameter `password` that is not defined before using it. you should define `var password` before this if or you should change this condition

Comment: I think I explain it bad. I want it to be type text in the beginning and change to type password when the user introduces the text. I edit the question to explain it better